# JQuery Mobile and Cordova app sample

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have heard mixed opinions on JQuery Mobile with PhoneGap/Cordova. The biggest complaint I hear is performance. I want to experience an app for myself.

Does anyone know of an app built with JQuery Mobile and distributed to the Apple App Store via PhoneGap/Cordova? I'd like to download the app and give it a try for myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apps built with PhoneGap

http://phonegap.com/app/feature

Apps built with jQueryMobile

http://www.jqmgallery.com/

I don't know of any specifically built with both together but I'm quite positive it has been done since it's a popular development choice to use both together.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I agree with your assessment. I've seen both of those pages previously. However, I'm yet to hear of them actually used together and actually deployed. I'm concerned about performance. That's why I wanted to get my hands on one.

Comment: Performance in general should be fine. I have also heard of someone using fastclick to help increase response time for touch interactions. https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick Performance will mostly depend on the device capabilities and the code you're writing. If you're writing an app to do genome sequencing, performance might be a problem. An app for some menu/page navigation and a modest amount of network requests shouldn't have a problem.